# How to get the full text format from mongodb database that inserted with input from reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

So the case is that i do post request from react to save recipe in the database.
the problem is that when i request to get the recipe its giving it to me without the spaces . example:

if the input value is: " Hello i am David
And i am 28 years old"

the mongodb gives me that in string like "Hello I am David And i am 28 years old"
without the line jump...

another example:
input:

1. apple
2. banana

mongodb gives me: 1. apple 2.banana

```
<textarea
          className="col-lg-12 mt-3 textarea"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          placeholder={label}
          name={name}
          value={data[name]}
           wrap="hard"
           cols="100"
           rows="20"
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely not a problem with react or mongo, but with styling when you display the value.

If you look in your mongodb at the value itself, you will probably see the value is `hello I am David\n And i am 28 years old`.

If you rendered this value in a `<div>` tag, it would display without the newline, as whitespace in html is collapsed by deafult.

You should try something like this:

```
<div stlye="white-space: pre-wrap;">
    { valueFromMongoDb }
</div>
```

[Reference on white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: and now the text is moving outside the div there is any solution?

Comment: If you use `pre-wrap` it will wrap when it gets to the edge but preserve the white space in the input.

Comment: whats is the best way to still wrap it and dont let the text go out from the div?

Comment: using `pre-wrap` should do that, if not, you need to share some more information such as what browser you're using, a screenshot, etc.

Comment: yes you right, i did 'pre' before and the text was all over the screen.. now its works! thanks